# How does the Wifi router know which PC to forward a request to, when some PC is running a server program like Apache/IIS?

Tags: apache, sockets, iis, server, wifi

I was studying about socket programming. What I understood is that it is a combination of an IP Address and a Port number.
Now suppose I have a listener running on my PC, which is connected to Wifi.
The requests to this listener over Internet should come to a public IP address and port number combination.
There may be multiple PC's connected to the Wifi I am connected to.
When a request comes to the Wifi router, how would it know which PC should it be forwarded to in the Wifi LAN?

Comment: It doesn't know, unless it is explicitly configured so (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding). Also, this should go to https://superuser.com/

Comment: @DusanBajic is correct.  Note that your "router" is likely doing "Network Address Translation", which is very different than normal packet routing.

Comment: @DusanBaji
I have added the question to superuser here:

https://superuser.com/questions/1250258/how-does-the-wifi-router-know-which-pc-to-forward-a-request-to-when-some-pc-is

In addition to this question, I have added a few more details there.

Thank you for your responses till now.

Can you please join the conversation on the superuser link provided above?

Comment: @ewindes Thank you for your comment. Please read my comment above.